# Why doesnt this code continue to remain in the conditional loop for more than one iteration?

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

i am creating a signup system that saves an email address and password to a file 'users.txt'. the script first checks if the file 'users.txt' contains an entry for the given email address and if found returns 'An Account with that email already exists' and then prompts the user again to enter an email address. the code works the first time returning the error message but if you enter the same email again it does not return with the same error message as intended instead it continues with the rest of the code. How do i remain in the loop until an email address is given that is not in the file? here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import getpass

class NewUser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.username = input('Enter your email address: ')
        checkUser = NewUser.userExists(self.username)
        while True:
            if checkUser == False:
                self.username = input('Enter your email address: ')
            if checkUser == True:
                break
        self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Choose a Password: ', stream=None)
        self.confirm = getpass.getpass(prompt='Confirm Password: ', stream=None)
        while True:
            if self.password != self.confirm:
                print('Passwords do not match, try again.')
                self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Choose a Password: ', stream=None)
                self.confirm = getpass.getpass(prompt='Confirm Password: ', stream=None)
            if self.password == self.confirm:
                break
        print('Account has been successfully created')
        with open('users.txt', 'a+') as f:
            f.write('\n')
            f.write(self.username)
            f.write(', ')
            f.write(self.password)
            f.close()

    def userExists(username):
        with open('users.txt', 'rb') as f:
            if bytes(username, encoding='utf-8') in f.read():
                print('An account with that email already exists.')
                return(False)
            else:
                return(True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are lot of issues in way you have structured your code, but we are going to focus only on problem you mentioned. i m just going to rewrite the code a bit to show what a solution can be hope that helps.

```
class NewUser:
    def __init__(self):
       user_exist = True
       while user_exist:
          self.username = input('Enter your email address: ')
          user_exist = NewUser.userExists(self.username)
          if user_exist:
             print('An account with that email already exists.')
          # here prompt for asking email will keep coming till entered email 
          # is not in given file
    
       pass_match = False
       while not pass_match:
            self.password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Choose a Password: ', stream=None)
            self.confirm = getpass.getpass(prompt='Confirm Password: ', stream=None)
            pass_match = self.password == self.confirm
            if not pass_match:
               print('Passwords do not match, try again.')

       print('Account has been successfully created')
       with open('users.txt', 'a+') as f:
          f.write(self.username+', '+ self.password+'\n')
          f.close()

   def userExists(username):
       with open('users.txt', 'rb') as f:
           return bytes(username, encoding='utf-8') in f.read()
```